# for loop required and dynamic css required through PHP

Tags: php, html, css

How can I avoid the following if's by for loop .. ??
also, how can I generates the css on run time .. ??

```
if ($string == 12 && $string1==23) $style="r16"; 
if ($string == 34 && $string1==45) $style="r17"; 
if ($string == 45  && $string1== 56 ) $style="r18"; 
if ($string == 56 && $string1== 67) $style="r19"; 
if ($string == 67 && $string1== 78 ) $style="r20"; 
if ($string == 78 && $string1== 89 ) $style="r21"; 
if ($string == 89 && $string1== 910) $style="r22"; 
if ($string == 910 && $string1== 1011) $style="r23"; 
if ($string == 1011 && $string1== 1112) $style="r24"; 
if ($string ==  1112 && $string1== 1213) $style="r25"; 
if ($string == 1213 && $string1==1314 ) $style="r26"; 
if ($string == 1314 && $string1==1415 ) $style="r27"; 
if ($string == 1415 && $string1==1516 ) $style="r28"; 
if ($string == 1516 && $string1==1617 ) $style="r29";
```

CSS required .. as follow

```
.r16{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r17{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r18{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r19{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r20{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r21{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r22{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r23{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r24{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r25{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r26{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r27{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r28{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
.r29{ text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px; }
```

Comment: what's the point when all the css is the same?

Comment: CSS can be differt .. eg margin may be different ..

Comment: What is the point in doing it in PHP? What's wrong with having all of the CSS on the page at once? Can you set up a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo of your page and explain what your CSS is doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the `if`s by using an array:

```
$styles = array('12,23' => 'r16',
                '34,45' => 'r17',
                ...
                '1516,1617' => 'r29'
               );
if (isset($styles["$string,$string1"])) {
    $style = $styles["$string,$string1"];
}
```

You could also use this array to generate the CSS. Make the values associative arrays containing the class name and CSS, e.g.

```
$styles = array('12,23' => array('class' => 'r16',
                                 'css' => 'text-align: left;padding-left: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;  margin: 10px 490px 0px 285px;'),
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$range_start_arr = array(12, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 910, 1011, 1112, 1213, 1314, 1415, 1516);
$range_end_arr = array(23, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 910, 1011, 1112, 1213, 1314, 1415, 1516, 1617);
for (i = 16; $i <= 29; $i++)
{
    $k = $i - 16;
    if($string == $range_start_arr[$k] && $string1 == $range_end_arr[$k]) $style = 'r'.$i;
}
```

I'm assuming `$string` and `$string1` are constants and you are just trying to shorten your code.

Comment: Arrays start at zero, you need to subtract 16 from $i.

Comment: Ok, it's an array now with for loop ... but I would prefer the "IF" way, if it's not hundreds of values/versions... better readable and maintainable imho

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid the following if's by for loop?

You can't! Where does $string and $string1 come from? Also, your css classes may not be calculated from $string(1), cause your "intervals" are not the same size nor linear.

> how can I generates the css on run time?

Instead of calling a .css file, you just put an .php file there which echos the computed styles.